# Codeigniter: login as admin user and login as employee user

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I'm currently working on `codeigniter framework` and I'm currently working on a project which is basically an admin/employee login system.

Currently I have been able to create a login form, and can successfully get a user to login, after having checked the user exists.

I just wanted to be pointed in the right direction as to how I could go about this to be able to login an employee user to an employees page, and an admin user to an admin page.

This is what I have at the moment, which is fully functioning using bootstrap as a front end framework. But allows any user to login.

By the way I have only one table name "employees" which consist only for employee user and admin user from mysql database.

Here is the view: (login.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=1,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=1" />
  <title> Login Form </title>

  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100italic,100,300italic,300,400italic,400,700italic,700,900italic,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/styles.css" />
  <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].oninvalid = function (e) {
      e.target.setCustomValidity("");
      if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
        switch (e.srcElement.id) {
          case "username":
          e.target.setCustomValidity("Username cannot be blank");
          break;
          case "pass":
          e.target.setCustomValidity("Password cannot be blank");
          break;
        }
      }
    };
    elements[i].oninput = function (e) {
      e.target.setCustomValidity("");
    };
  }
})
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.back{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
</style>

<section class="container">
      <section class="login-form">
    <form class="form-signin" action="goClock" method="post" role="login">
               <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/easypay.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="username" name='user' required id="username" autocomplete="off" autofocus  />
        <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" name='password' required id="pass" required />
       <?php

            if(!empty($login_error)) {
              echo $login_error;
            }

       ?>  
            <button name='login' class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary" value=" LOGIN " type="submit" id="button2">Login</button>  
</form>
        <p class="text-center" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 60;" id="demo"></p>

            <script>
            var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

            function myTimer() {
              var d = new Date();
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
            }
            </script>
</section>
</section>
<div class="back">
  <input class="btn btn-warning" action="action" type="button" value="<- Back" onclick="location.href = 'index';" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the controller: (home.php)

```
   public function goClock($message = null) {
            $this->load->view('imports/header');
            $this->load->view('imports/menu');

            if (!is_null($this->input->post('login'))) {
                $username = $this->input->post('user');
                $password = $this->input->post('password');

                $userdata = $this->model_home->get_userinfo($username, $password);

                $_SESSION['is_loggedin'] = true;  

                if ($userdata !== false) {
                    $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
                    redirect('home/goHome');
                }else {
                    $data['login_error'] = '<p style="font-size: 16px; color: red;" align="center">Invalid Username or Password</p>';
                    $this->load->view('login', $data);
                }
            }else {
                $data['username'] = $this->input->post('user');
                $data['password'] = $this->input->post('password');
                $this->load->view('clock', $data);
            }
        }
```

And finally here is the model: (model_home.php)

```
public function get_userinfo($username = null, $password = null) {
        if ($username && $password) {
            $this->db->select('username, password, empnum');
            $this->db->where('username', $username);
            $this->db->where('password', $password);
            $query = $this->db->get('employees');
            if ($query->num_rows()) {
                return $query->result_array()[0];
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Just to clarify I have only one controller, my main controller by default which is home.php. In conclusion my aim is to be able to redirect an admin user to admin.php and to be able to redirect a employee user to employee.php (Hasn't been created yet).

P.S I already have a column in my table in PhpMyAdmin called "employees".

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add one extra column in Database named as user_type and Set default value=0 for that and for "admin" set it 1.
Now modify your query like this:

```
if ($username && $password) {
            $this->db->select('username, password, empnum,user_type');
            $this->db->where('username', $username);
            $this->db->where('password', $password);
            $query = $this->db->get('employees');
            if ($query->num_rows()) {
                return $query->result_array()[0];
            }
        }
```

Now check the $userdata[] array value having user_type key if it is 1 then

```
$this->load->view('admin', $data);
```

else he is user_type = 0 which means employee
    $this->load->view('employee', $data);

NOTE:I can provide the way but here you have to modify your array key and view name as per the need.

Comment: one more suggestion use inbuilt array functions to reduce the code complexity use row_aray() to get the query result directly...No need to point out index

Comment: Can you help me or provide me a full code of MVC? Please, thank you.

Comment: sorry i can't give you a fish directly..try fishing-rod instead

Answer (score 0):

First create a filed with name `usertype` in your database `employees` table.

Run this query in your phpMyadmin database

```
  ALTER TABLE `employees` ADD `usertype` ENUM('user','employee') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user' ;
```

and add following code on your `Model`

```
 public function get_userinfo($username = null, $password = null) {
    if ($username && $password) {
        $this->db->select('username, password, empnum,usertype');
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get('employees');
        if ($query->num_rows()) {
            return $query->row();
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

And on your controller

```
public function goClock($message = null) {
        $this->load->view('imports/header');
        $this->load->view('imports/menu');

        if (!is_null($this->input->post('login'))) {
            $username = $this->input->post('user');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            $userdata = $this->model_home->get_userinfo($username, $password);

            $_SESSION['is_loggedin'] = true;  

            if ($userdata !== false) {
               if($userdata->usertype=='user'){ # if user then redirect to user page

                  redirect('home/goHome');
               }else{
                  # If employee redirect to admin page
               }
            }else {
                $data['login_error'] = '<p style="font-size: 16px; color: red;" align="center">Invalid Username or Password</p>';
                $this->load->view('login', $data);
            }
        }else {
            $data['username'] = $this->input->post('user');
            $data['password'] = $this->input->post('password');
            $this->load->view('clock', $data);
        }
    }
```